# How to use custom types in Java IDL

Tags: java, eclipse, corba

In my Java CORBA program, I want to use a special `Calendar` type I created to extend the built-in `GregorianCalendar`.

My `Calendar` has some special methods that I want to define in the IDL file. However it doesn't seem to be working.

```
module HotelServer {
    interface Hotel {
        enum RoomType {SINGLE_ROOM, DOUBLE_ROOM, FAMILY_ROOM};

        struct Calendar {
            unsigned short day;
            unsigned short month;
            unsigned short year;
            boolean equals(in Calendar calendar);
            boolean isEarlierThan(in Calendar calendar);
            boolean isLaterThan(in Calendar calendar);
        };
 .....
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't seem to be working"

Comment: Eclipse shows me an error on the `(` in `...equals(in..` and won't compile into the Java files it should

Comment: what is the prefix `in` for?

Comment: @redFIVE it's part of the IDL syntax

Answer (score 0):

A struct may not have operations in IDL, you have to remove the operations `equals`, `isEarlierThan` and `isLaterThan`. These operations you have to implement then in Java as separation operations. The other option is to use a valuetype instead of a struct.